# Special characters like å ä ö are not recognized by operators in VS Code running PowerShell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, special-characters

If using `-like` or `-match` operators in VSCode and PowerShell, å ä ö are not recognized. You simply do not get a hit when running the script, it comes back negative.
The exact same operator in the terminal windows gives back True.
Example:

```
$String = "Denna sträng innehåller ordet nötter!"
If ($String -match "nötter")
    {
        Write-host "True"
    }
else { Write-host "False" }
```

Comes back False.
Running:

```
($String -match "nötter") in the Terminal
```

returns True
The script is created in VSCode, from File New, Save as .ps1

Comment: Make sure you save the file in an appropriate encoding.

Comment: works for me in VSCode 1.9.2, PowerShell Integrated Console with PSv5.1 and PowerShell Extension 1.5.1

Comment: works for me as expected as well. Same environment like @vrdse

Comment: To add to @Bill_Stewart's comment: be sure to save your .ps1 file _with a BOM_. VSCode creates BOM-_less_ UTF-8 files by default. PowerShell Core correctly interprets such files, but Windows PowerShell does not.